# Overriding layout file Symfony (Aimeos Symfony Bundle)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have a problem with overriding default template from `app/Resources` folder to my bundle resource folder. I have installed **Aimeos Symfony bundle**. And I get this error with opening list route. I moved all view files from app folder to bundle resource. Here is my folder structure project tree:

[image: project tree]

But i get this error trying to access **/list** route of Aimeos. I guess it has a wrong path **main error**:

[image: main error]

Comment: So, did you read [the documentation](https://aimeos.org/docs/Developers/Html_frontend/Overwrite_existing_templates)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why are you "moved all view files from app folder to bundle resource"?
2. Please, carefully read the installation manual, especially this step - [Symfony/Adapt base template](https://aimeos.org/docs/Symfony/Adapt_base_template).

So there was two ways how you got this error - you missed this installation step or just moved out `app/Resources/view/base.html.twig` that is important to see `/list` route.